# Combinatory Logic formula obtained from lambda term, proof?

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

I translated the following $\lambda$-term:

$z(\lambda b.ba)(tt)(\lambda y.y)$

in the following CL formula:

$z(CIa)(tt)I$

through the Markov algorithm.

Now I'd like to prove the translation was correct, and I know that's done by applying arguments to such CL formula and execute each constant by its rule.

If I apply it this way

$z(CIa)(tt)I y b$

the I constant is run first, since it has the required arguments, thus obtaining the following:

$z(CIa)(tt) y b$

but I don't know how to further proceed, "pushing" the $b$ inside, in order to "activate" the $C$ constant.